# Query in Dynamo DB without hashkey or scan

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am looking to query on Dynamo DB without HashKey. I have tried using the scan but it is expensive so looking for some other alternatives.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

Comment: Tried like this :                                                                               filter.put("id", new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(id)));
            scanExpression.setScanFilter(filter);
   //TableNamess is the table name
            list = dynamoDBMapper.scan(TableNamess.class, scanExpression, dynamoDBOperations.getTableNameOverride(tableName));

Comment: Please update the question by clicking [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35861013/edit) link, which is available just below your question content. Question allows lot of formatting features than comments.

Answer (score 50):

I should start by saying that querying a DynamoDB table without knowing the hash key can't be done. And it makes sense.

Now, whether the hash key you want to use is the **primary key** of the table or not, is up to you.

Suppose, for instance, that you have the following table:

```
╔══════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ course_id (Hash Key) ║      course_name       ║    teacher     ║
╠══════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 324234               ║ Node.js for Dummies    ║ Ryan Dahl      ║
║ 213323               ║ How to train your cat  ║ Jackson Galaxy ║
║ 324090               ║ Cat Logic              ║ Jackson Galaxy ║
║ 763298               ║ Diving into .NET       ║ Eric Lippert   ║
╚══════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

The table's primary key and hash key is `course_id`, which is fine. Providing unique hash keys allows your table to be split into multiple partitions.

But, what if we want to get **All the courses that Jackson Galaxy is teaching**?

We don't know the `course_id` of those courses, that's what we want to get. So we find ourselves without knowing the items' hash key values.

That's where **GSI** come into play. **Global Secondary Indexes** let you define a different hash key for your table. **Note that it will not change the primary hash key - `course_id` will still be the table's hash key.**

GSI only provides an additional hash key for you to be able to make more complex queries.

Let's say we add a GSI named `teacher_index`, and we say that `teacher` will be our hash key, and `course_id` will be our range key (We need to specify a range key, because `teacher` alone as a hash key will generate duplicate entries).

Now we can query our `teacher_index` and pass in `Jackson Galaxy` as a hash key value. The results would be `213323 - How to train your cat` and `324090 - Cat Logic`.

Comment: Thanks for a really simple and straightforward answer.

Comment: Great answer, help me to understand the GSI concept, but suppose I want to create a search function for the teachers, how can I user `contains` if teacher is the hash_key ?

Answer (score 11):

I partially agree with the answer posted by Matias. You can create a Global Secondary Index on the table (with a hash key and an **optional** range key).

However, **I don't agree with what he says in his answer later**: "We need to specify a range key, because teacher alone as a hash key will generate duplicate entries". I can't comment below his answer because I do not have enough reputation. For some reason, I am not able to edit his answer.

From the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForGSI.html):

> Global Secondary indices do not enforce uniqueness

Hence, range keys for Global Secondary Indices (GSI's) are optional and the composite key for a GSI need not uniquely identify any record.