# Create a search function using Dynamodb and boto3

Tags: python, database, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to understand how to create a search function using dynamodb. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35917522/3307382) helped me to understand better the use of Global Secondary Indexes but I still have some questions. Suppose we have an structure like this and a GSI called `last_name_index`:

```
+------+-----------+----------+---------------+
| User | FirstName | LastName |     Email     |
+------+-----------+----------+---------------+
| 1001 | Test      | Test     | test@mail.com |
| 1002 | Jonh      | Doe      | jdoe@mail.com |
| 1003 | Another   | Test     | mail@mail.com |
+------+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

Using boto3 I can search now for a user if I know the last name:

```
table.query(
         IndexName = "last_name_index",
         KeyConditionExpression=Key('LastName').eq(name)
)
```

**But** what if want to search for users and I only know part of the last name? I know there is a `contains` function on boto3 but this only works with non index keys. Do I need to change the GSI? Or is there something I'm missing? I want to be able to do something like:

```
table.query(
         IndexName = "last_name_index",
         KeyConditionExpression=Key('LastName').contains(name) # part of the name
)
```

Comment: You can only specify exact partition keys in a query. If you want to use 'contains' you have to do a scan, or specify a different attribute as the partition key.

Comment: Scan may not be the best when we have a lot of data. Which attribute would you use @Stu as the partition key?